# pagination in codeigniter not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have view that get all data from database and i wont to make pagination in my code.

i will try this way to make pagination in my site, but its not display pagination.

the view are like :-

```
<ol class="timeline2 clear">
  <li class="spine">

  </li>

  <?php 
  $counter=0;
  //print_r($response);
  foreach ($response as $row) { 
  if($counter % 2 == 0){$class= "left";} else $class="right";
  ?>

   <li class="<?=$class ?>">
    <i class="pointer"></i>
    <div class="unit">

      <!-- Story -->
      <div class="storyUnit">
        <div class="imageUnit">
         <? if (empty($row->pic)) { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="images/nopic.png"></a>
          <? } else  { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="uploads/<?php echo $row->pic; ?>"></a>
          <div id="delpost" style="float:left">
          <a href="./myaccount/deletePostInProfile/<?=$row->ev_id;?>" id="deletepost">X</a>
          </div>
          <? } ?>
          <div class="imageUnit-content">
            <h4><a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $row->ev_date ?></p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <p> <?php echo $row->ev_text; ?><br />
        <? if (!empty($row->ev_pic)) { ?>
        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row->ev_pic ?>" width="250" height="250"</p>
        <? } ?></p>

      </div>
      <!-- / Story -->

      <!-- Units -->
      <ol class="storyActions" id="storyActions<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>">
<?
$selectComment = mysql_query("select * from comment,users where 
comment.co_postid = '".$row->ev_id."'
and comment.co_userid = users.id order by co_date DESC ");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($selectComment)){
?>
      <div id="resultcomment<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>"></div>
      <div id="resultcomment" style="border-top:1px solid #fff;">
      <a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
      <img src="uploads/<?=$rows["pic"];?>" width="32" height="32" class="rightc" />
      </a>
      <b><a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?=$rows["fullname"]; ?></a></b>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span><?=$rows["co_comment"]; ?></span>
      <br />
      <span class="commentdate"><?=$rows["co_date"]; ?></span></br></div>
<? } ?>      

      <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <input type="text" class="commentprofile" id="comment<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" name="comment<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" size="41" />
       <input type="hidden" id="postid<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" name="postid<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" size="41" value="<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" />
       <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="add_comment(<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>)">ارسل</button>
       </form>

      </ol>
      <!-- / Units -->

    </div>
  </li>

   <?php $counter++; } ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</ol>

<? } ?>

    <div>

         <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

    </div>
```

and my controller :-

```
public function profile($user_id) {

        $check  = new User();
        $ex = $check->where('id',$user_id)->count();
        if( $ex == 0){ redirect('./home'); }
        else {
        $user = new User($user_id);


/************************************** Post *******************************************************************/
        $this->load->model('blog');

        if(isset($_POST['post'])){
        // Config setup
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/myaccount/profile/'.$user_id.'/';
        $config['total_rows'] = 20;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['num_links'] = 5;
        // Initialize
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        if(strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) 
        {
        $pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');

        if ($this->input->post('post') == ''){$type="image";} else {$type="image-with-text";}
        }

        else {$pic = ""; $type = "text"; }

            $result = $this->blog->addPost($_SESSION['user_id'], $type  , $this->input->post('post'),$pic);
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $result = $this->blog->getPost($user_id, 0 , 10);
        $this->template->build("profile" , array("response"=>$result));     
        }
        else{
        $this->template->build('registration_view',$this->data);
        }


        $this->data['user'] = $user;
        $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;
        $this->template->set_layout('myaccount');
        $this->template->build('profile',$this->data);


        }
    }
```

the module :-

```
function getPost($user_id, $from, $to) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM events,users 
      where events.ev_user_id  = '".$user_id."'
      and events.ev_user_id = users.id  
      order by events.ev_date DESC limit 10");



    return $query->result();

}
```

why the pagination not display in my site ??

Answer (score 0):

In the controller after you initialize the pagination:

```
$this->data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Then in the view where you want the pagination links to appear:

```
echo $pagination_links;
```

You are trying to echo them in your view without creating them first in the controller. The example in the documentation is sort of bad in that it's just showing you to echo them out in the controller itself.